# window scrollbar shifting element over by about a pixel

Tags: html, css

I have a simple web app that shows a list of twitch streamers, and the list can be longer or shorter depending on whether the user wants to show who's online or offline, the problem is that when goin from long list to short list or vice versa, the window scrollbar pops in and shifts one of my elements over by about a pixel. It might not even be that noticeable but it is driving me crazy. I've tried it in chrome and safari and it didn't have the problem in safari so I think it might be something weird with chrome.

Here is the specific CSS-

```
.btn-col {
  padding: 0px;
  .cat-btn {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    z-index: 0;

    .down-triangle {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      border-top: 20px solid black;
      border-left: 20px solid transparent;
      border-right: 20px solid transparent;
      transition: all .3s ease;
      z-index: -10;
    }

    .vr {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      right: 0px;
      height: 20px;
      border-right: 2px solid $purple;
    }
  }
  #all-btn {
    color: $purple;
    #all-triangle {
      border-top: 15px solid white;
      bottom: -15px;
    }
  }
  #online-btn {
    color: $green;

    #online-triangle {
      border-top: 15px solid white;
    }
  }
  #offline-btn {
    color: $red;

    #offline-triangle {
      border-top: 15px solid white;
    }
  }
}
```

And a link to the codepen -http://codepen.io/Davez01d/pen/MyepzJ?editors=0110

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do anything to avoid it. The scrollbar is necessary since the user list gets longer, and if you remove it you won't be able to scroll down (easily). You can eventually try to set it `hidden` and make your own custom scrollbar like [THIS](http://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/) or [THIS](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Comment: I don't want to remove the scrollbar, I'm more trying to figure out why the scrollbar is effecting that element and not others